# Spring Validation: ConstraintViolationException for @Pattern due to password encoding

Tags: spring-boot

I'm just implementing a basic CRUD service where a user can be created in the database with their password matching a certain regex and being encoded using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

My tests are failing due to a `ConstraintViolationException` on the password saying that it does not satisfy the regex requirement:

```swift
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.hoaxify.hoaxify.user.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must match "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,50}$"', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.hoaxify.hoaxify.user.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}'}
```

It wasn't getting caught in my `@ExceptionHandler` since it was throwing a `ConstraintViolationException` and not a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.  I debugged and found that, while it was trying to match to the given regex, the value for the password itself was showing as:
`$2a$10$pmRUViwj3Ey4alK0eqT1Dulz4BpGSlSReHyBR28K6bIE4.LZ7nYWG`
while the password being passed in was:
`P4ssword`

So it appears the validation is being run on the encrypted password and *not* the raw password.  I thought the validation should occur on the object received in the `createUser` method - before any other manipulation occurred.

Any help on why this is happening and how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Note:

- Validation works for all other fields

#### UserController

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("{my/path}")
class UserController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @PostMapping
    fun createUser(@Valid @RequestBody user: User): GenericResponse {
        userService.save(user)
        return GenericResponse("Saved user")
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    fun handleValidationException(exception: MethodArgumentNotValidException, request: HttpServletRequest): ApiError {
        val error = ApiError(400, "Validation error", request.servletPath)

        val bindingResult = exception.bindingResult
        bindingResult.fieldErrors.forEach {
            error.validationErrors[it.field] = it.defaultMessage ?: "invalid"
        }

        return error
    }
}
```

#### User

```kotlin
@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long,
    @field:NotBlank
    @field:Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    var username: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    @field:Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    var displayName: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    @field:Pattern(regexp = """^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,50}$""")
    var password: String
)
```

#### UserService

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val passwordEncoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()
) {

    fun save(user: User): User {
        user.password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.password)
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

#### UserControllerTest

(relevant test)

```kotlin
@Test
fun postUser_whenUserIsValid_receiveOk() {
    val user = User(
        0,
        "test-user",
        "test-display",
        "P4ssword"
    )
    val response: ResponseEntity<Any> = testRestTemplate.postForEntity(API_USERS_BASE, user, Any::class.java)
    assertThat(response.statusCode).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same entity in the controller as in the service. So in the controller, it works as you expect. But in the service, you update the unencrypted password with the encrypted one and save that to the database. When you save to the database, the validation annotations are also checked, triggering the `ConstraintViolationException`.

The best option is to create a separate object for the controller. For example, create a `CreateUserRequest` class which is similar to the `User` entity, but only contains the fields that the controller needs. You can add your validation annotations there. Then in the service, convert the `CreateUserRequest` instance to a `User` entity. On the user class, remove the `@Pattern` validation since you don't want to validate the encrypted password.

Comment: I had thought about a separate request DTO, but the video tutorial I was following was using the same object and everything worked, so I was getting stuck trying to figure that out. The instructor was using Java whereas I'm using Kotlin, so not sure if there's a subtle difference there as far as how this operates.  Thank you for getting me going in the right direction